# How can I annotate source code to stop valgrind's DRD tool complain about data race?

Tags: multithreading, valgrind

How can I annotate source code (see below) to stop valgrind's DRD tool complain about data race?

I think this source doesn't contain any data race, but DRD thinks otherwise. This is because common synchronization primitives (like mutexes) not used in this case. The code relies on possibility of CPU to swap 's' pointer atomically.

See comments in source below.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <valgrind/drd.h>

pthread_t t1, t2;

struct S {
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct S *volatile s;

void *f1(void *arg)
{
    ANNOTATE_BENIGN_RACE(&s, "");
    (void)arg;
    int n=0;
    while (1) {
        usleep(100000);
        if (__sync_fetch_and_add(&s, 0) != 0) continue;

        struct S *p=malloc(sizeof(struct S));
        assert(p!=NULL);

        p->x = ++n; // Conflicts with this line
        p->y = ++n; // Conflicts with this line

        p=__sync_lock_test_and_set(&s, p);
        __sync_synchronize();
        assert(p==NULL);
    }
}

void *f2(void *arg)
{
    ANNOTATE_BENIGN_RACE(&s, "");
    (void)arg;
    while (1) {
        usleep(150000);
        struct S *p=__sync_fetch_and_add(&s, 0);
        if (p==NULL) continue;

        volatile int z;
        z=p->x;     // Conflicting load (DRD complains on this lines)
        z+=p->y;    // Conflicting load

        free(p);
        __sync_lock_release(&s);
    }
}


int main()
{
    ANNOTATE_BENIGN_RACE(&s, "");
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, f1, NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, f2, NULL);
    while (1) {
        usleep(75000);
        printf("%p\n", __sync_fetch_and_add(&s, 0));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the compiler translates this, so that there is no reordering and the atomicity also remains intact - before silencing the grinding tool ;-) ?